# Show the series of functions converges uniformly on the intervals indicated.

Tags: real-analysis

The series of function is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(xlnx)^k$ on $(0,1]$.

I tried Weierstrass M-test to show the series is uniform convergence.

$\forall x\in (0,1]$, $(xlnx)^k = (\frac{lnx}{\frac{1}{x}})^k\leq(\frac{0}{\frac{1}{x}})^k$

As $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{0}{\frac{1}{x}})^k=0$ which is converges.

Therefore $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(xlnx)^k$ converges uniformly on $(0,1]$.

I am not sure I did it correct or not because $0$ is seldom used for comparison but I cannot figured out other constant that can be used to compare with this series.

Comment: The Weierstrass M-test requires you be able to bound the absolute value of the terms in your series with positive numbers. That is, you must show that there is a sequence of **positive** numbers $\{M_k\}$ such that $|(xln(x))^k| \leq M_k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after graphing several powers of $x\ln(x)$, I noticed that the absolute value of $(x\ln(x))^k$ *seemed* to be no more than $\frac{1}{2^k}$ on the given interval

**Claim:** For all $x \in (0,1]$, $|(x\ln(x))^k| \leq \frac{1}{2^k}$for all $k = 1, 2, \ldots$

For $k=1$, we first try to find extrema of the function $f$ given by $f(x) = x\ln(x)$. 
Taking the first derivative, we find that $f'(x) = \ln(x) +1 \implies f'= 0$ when $x = e^{-1}$. We see that this is the only critical point, and it is easy to verify that $f(x)$ has an absolute minimum at $x = e^{-1}$. We see that $f(e^{-1}) = -\frac{1}{e} \approx -0.37$. Also, $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x\ln(x) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$. With all of this information together, we may deduce that $|x\ln(x)| < \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \in (0,1]$.

Suppose the claim is true when $k = r$ for some $r \geq 1$. So, $|(x\ln(x))^r| \leq \frac{1}{2^r}$.

Observe that 
$$|(x\ln(x))^{r+1}| = |(x\ln(x))^r(x\ln(x))|= |(x\ln(x))^r||x\ln(x)| < (\frac{1}{2^r})(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2^{r+1}}$$

By mathematical induction, it follows that our claim is true.

Since the series $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}$$ converges, our result follows by the Weierstrass M-Test.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not correct. The terms of the series can be positive when $k$ is even, so how can they be $\le 0?$ Also you may be a little confused about how to apply Weierstrass M correctly.

Hint: Find the maximum $M$ of $|x\ln x|$ in the interval. Hopefully $M<1.$ If so, then $|x\ln x|^k\le M^k$ for all $k$ ...